# Using another macro in a macro_rules without requiring `extern crate` in rust

Tags: macros, rust

Is there a way to "re-export" `#[macro_use] extern crate` similar to `pub use` so that users of a macro using macros do not have to manually add these dependent `extern crate`s?

The rest of the question is an example to illustrate.

In `src/lib.rs`, note that the `id` macro is using the `lazy_static` macro:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! id {
    () => {
        lazy_static! {
            static ref NUMBER : std::sync::atomic::AtomicUsize =
                std::sync::atomic::AtomicUsize::new(0);
        }
        return NUMBER.fetch_add(1, std::sync::atomic::Ordering::SeqCst);
    }
}
```

In `examples/example.rs`, we need an `extern crate` line for each macro, even though we're just using the `id` macro directly:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate id_macro;
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

fn new_id() -> usize {
    id!();
}

fn main() {
    println!("id {}", new_id()); // prints "id 0"
    println!("id {}", new_id()); // prints "id 1"
}
```

In the example, it would be great if the user of `id_macro` could use `id!` without knowing about `lazy_static`. Is there a way to "re-export" `extern crate` similar to `pub use` to make the following lines go away from the example?

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an unstable [`macro_reexport`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29638) attribute.

However, Rust is working on making macros ([2.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39412)) behave like normal items that support `pub use`, so this attribute won't be stable and will become obsolete.

Comment: Thanks @Kornel. If anyone comes across this, for `lazy_static`, what I needed specifically was:
```#![feature(macro_reexport)]
#[macro_reexport(lazy_static,
__lazy_static_internal,
__lazy_static_create)] extern crate lazy_static;```
Quite the mouthful! And of course now only compiles on nightly.